# Access data from the URL to java using thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I started to working on thymeleaf, so after submitting the form I end up getting this URL:

**URL**

> http://localhost:8080/submit?name=xyz&age=20&dropdown=male

so how should I get the value of individual elements to java controller?

In java part, I should be able to load them into their respective datatypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, yes later I was able to solve it

> **Step1**Create an HTML plage **GetDetails.HTML**

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Details</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" th:action="@{PATH OF ACTION}" method="get" th:object="${details}">
       <input type="text" name="name" th:field="*{name}"/> 
       <input type="text" name="age" th:field="*{age}"/> 
       <select name="option" th:field="*{option}">
       <option value="male">male</option> 
       <option value="female">female</option>
        </select>
<input type="submit" value="search"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

> **Step2** Create a Model class in java (POJO)

```
class Details{
private String name;
private int age;
//getters and setters
//constructors
}
```

> NOTE: Class name must be same as the object name given in HTML page
>
> **Step3** Controller part in Java

```
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String search(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("details", new Details());
        return "GetDetails";
    }
```

> **Step4** REST controller

```
    @GetMapping(value = "PATH OF ACTION")
    public List<Details> getAll(@ModelAttribute Details details) {
    // Business service 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To grab GET parameters (URL parameters), use request.getParameter

```
String name = request.getParameter("name");    
String age = request.getParameter("age");
String dropdown = request.getParameter("dropdown");
```

Note that these are all strings, if you want other datatypes you will need to parse them and handle any errors.